# PostgreSQL Query : update parent row basis of child rows

Tags: postgresql

We have a tasks app with an optional 1 level of parent child relationship, where any row which is a parent doesn't have any parent of its own, but is primarily a filler to link related tasks if any as siblings.

We were initially not concerned in setting completed=true for the parent rows. However, we now want to set completed=true for any parents with *ALL* child tasks set completed=true and thus need a PostgreSQL query for the same.

```
testdb=> \d tasks;
                              Table "public.tasks"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id        | integer |           | not null | nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass)
 parent_id | integer |           |          | 
 completed | boolean |           | not null | false
Indexes:
    "tasks_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "tasks_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tasks(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tasks" CONSTRAINT "tasks_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tasks(id)

testdb=> select * from tasks order by id;
 id | parent_id | completed 
----+-----------+-----------
  1 |           | f
  2 |           | f
  3 |           | f
  4 |           | f
  5 |         2 | f
  6 |         2 | f
  7 |         2 | t
  8 |         2 | f
  9 |         2 | t
 10 |           | f
 11 |           | f
 12 |           | f
 13 |         4 | t
 14 |         4 | t
 15 |         4 | t
 16 |         4 | t
 17 |         4 | t
 18 |         4 | t
 19 |        11 | t
 20 |        11 | t
```

After executing the desired query, completed=true for parent tasks id 4 and 11, with all respective child Tasks 13-18(Children of Task 4), 19-20(Children of Task 11) already having completed=true.
task id=2 completed=false remains as is, because completed=false for child tasks 5,6 and 8.

OVERKILL : There is only 1 level of parent child relationship right now, however it would be great to know the solution for an n-level non-circular parent child task tree.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Regret the confusion. Improved the question. Hopefully :)

Comment: Look at the `bool_and` aggregate function. Use a trigger to maintain redundant data.

Comment: @batfan47 I'm still missing a question mark. Are you having trouble writing this update query? Can you show us what you tried or what approaches you thought of?

Answer (score 1):

There's a self-explanatory aggregate function [`every()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.11.1.1.1), which does the same as `bool_and()` that [Laurenz Albe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402000/postgresql-query-update-parent-row-basis-of-child-rows#comment134723204_76402000) while having a nicer sound to it: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/aYstSSmf)

```sql
with parent_task_summaries as (
  select t1.id, every(subtask.completed) as all_done
  from tasks t1 left join tasks subtask
      on t1.parent_id is null
      and t1.id=subtask.parent_id
  group by t1.id
)
update tasks t1 
set completed=all_done
from parent_task_summaries t2
where t1.id=t2.id
and t1.parent_id is null
returning t1.*;
```

I like that `every(subtask.completed)` here means "every subtask completed", word-for-word.

For n-level, you can use [a recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) that offers cycle detection through `not is cycle` condition.